# Jquery Clone Select with Inline Onchange Function and multiple ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, clone, html-select

I have a select drop down that is populated with numbers14 from an ajax request. When a number is selected from the dropdown, 2 signs are populated as options. These signs are the result of an onchange function attached to the select with another ajax request to get the signs.

I need to clone both the select dropdown and populate new signs based on the selected number. Only the select is seen on the page first, then when a selection is made, the signs should appear. I need it to be the same display for each clone with new ids for the select and sign options. My problem is, adding the new id's to the clone function does not work with the onchange request at all. No signs show in the clone and adding new id's to the Sign function, makes both selects change both sets of signs when selected. New signs don't populate.

I need the first selection to only provide signs for the number selected and the clone to only provide signs for that number selected. How can I achieve this?

```
<form id=entry1"> 
<select class="select_sign select_ttl w-100" name="SignID" id="signId" onchange='GetSign(this)' data-request-url="@Url.Action("GetJsonSignNumbers", "Product")"></select>

<div  id="box-1" name='show'></div>
</form>
<button> Clone</button>
```

```
//Populate route dropdownlist
var signNumber = $(".select_sign");
signNumber.empty().append('<option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Loading.....</option>');

$.ajax({
    url: signNumber.data('request-url'),
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (response) {
        ddlroute.empty().append('<option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Sign</option>');
        $.each(response, function () {
            signNumber.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
        });
    }
});

function GetSign(sign) {


    $.ajax({
        url: "/Product/GetJsonsign",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: { id: sign.value },
        success: function (data) {
            var items = ""

            data = '\
                    <div class="row btn-group-sm " data-toggle="buttons">\
                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">\
                            <div>\
                                <label class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-raised sign-label-0 w-100 active" for="data[0].sign0" style="border - radius: 0!important; " checked>' + data[0].sign0 + '\
                                    <input class="input_sign_0" type="radio" name="Sign" id="data[0].sign0" value="' + data[0].sign0 + '" autocomplete="off">\
                                </label>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">\
                                          <div>\
                                <label class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-raised sign-label-1 w-100" for="data[0].sign1" style="border-radius:0 !important; ">' + data[0].sign1 + '\
                                    <input class="input_sign_1" type="radio" name="Sign" id="data[0].sign1" value="' + data[0].sign1 + '" autocomplete="off">\
                                </label>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>';

            items = data;

            $("div[name=show]").html(items);
        }
           
    });
}

function Sign(sign) {


    $.ajax({
        url: "/Product/GetJsonsign",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: { id: sign.value },
        success: function (data) {
            var items = ""

            data = '\
                    <div class="row btn-group-sm " data-toggle="buttons">\
                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">\
                            <div>\
                                <label class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-raised sign-label-0 w-100 active" for="data[0].sign0" style="border - radius: 0!important; " checked>' + data[0].sign0 + '\
                                    <input class="input_sign_0" type="radio" name="Sign" id="data[0].sign0" value="' + data[0].sign0 + '" autocomplete="off">\
                                </label>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">\
                                          <div>\
                                <label class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-raised sign-label-1 w-100" for="data[0].sign1" style="border-radius:0 !important; ">' + data[0].sign1 + '\
                                    <input class="input_sign_1" type="radio" name="Sign" id="data[0].sign1" value="' + data[0].sign1 + '" autocomplete="off">\
                                </label>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>';

            items = data;

            $("div[name=show]").html(items);
        }
           
    });
}

function cloneForm() {
    var num = $(".clonedInput").length;
    var newNum = new Number(num + 1);
    var newForm = $("#entry" + num).clone()
        .attr("id", "entry" + newNum);

   newForm
        .find("#box-1").empty();

    newForm
        .find(".input_sign_0")
        .attr("id", "Sign" + newNum + "_ID-0")
        .attr("name", "Sign" + newNum + "")
        .val([]);
    newForm
        .find(".input_sign_1")
        .attr("id", "Sign" + newNum + "_ID-1")
        .attr("name", "Sign" + newNum + "")
        .val([]);
}

$('button').click(function(){
cloneForm();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `GetSign` function you are using `$("div[name=show]")` to add result from ajax this will target all div where match found instead you are already passing `this` inside your function you can use `$(sign).closest("form").find("div[name=show]")` this will find `div` where select has been change then add your result there .

Also , inside your `cloneForm()` function you are getting length of `clonedInputs` but there is no such class with that name. So, instead of that you can just that length of `form` and just `add 1` to it then add this new value to your `id` of new form.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var signNumber = $(".select_sign");
signNumber.empty().append('<option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Loading.....</option>');

/*$.ajax({
 //some codes....
 ddlroute.empty().append('<option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Sign</option>');*/
//just for demo...

signNumber.empty().append('<option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Sign</option>');
signNumber.append($("<option></option>").val(1).html("abc"));
signNumber.append($("<option></option>").val(2).html("abc2"));
/*$.each(response, function() {
    //some..other codes..
});*/

function GetSign(sign) {
  /* $.ajax({
     //some codes..
     success: function(data) {*/
  var items = "";
  data = '\ <div class="row btn-group-sm " data-toggle="buttons">\<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">\<div>\ <label class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-raised sign-label-0 w-100 active" for="data[0].sign0" style="border - radius: 0!important; " checked> 1\ <input class="input_sign_0" type="radio" name="Sign" id="data[0].sign0" value="1" autocomplete="off">\</label>\</div>\</div>\ <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">\ <div>\<label class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-raised sign-label-1 w-100" for="data[0].sign1" style="border-radius:0 !important; ">2\ <input class="input_sign_1" type="radio" name="Sign" id="data[0].sign1" value="2" autocomplete="off">\ </label>\
</div>\ </div>\ </div>';
  items = data;
  //get closest form then name div ...add result there
  $(sign).closest("form").find("div[name=show]").html(items);
  /*}
  });*/
}

$('button').click(function() {
  cloneForm();
})


function cloneForm() {
  //check length of form
  var newNum = $("#all_divs form").length + 1;
  //clone first form
  var newForm = $("#all_divs form:first").clone()
    .attr("id", "entry" + newNum);
  newForm.attr("class", "clonedInput");
  newForm
    .find("[name=show]").empty();
  //append to div
  $(newForm).appendTo($("#all_divs"))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="all_divs">
  <form id="entry1">
    <select class="select_sign select_ttl w-100" name="SignID" id="signId" onchange='GetSign(this)' data-request-url="@Url.Action(" GetJsonSignNumbers ", "Product ")"></select>

    <div id="box-1" name='show'></div>
  </form>
</div>
<button> Clone</button>
```